# Polymer binding on-tap event on inner-h-t-m-l

Tags: javascript, event-handling, polymer, polymer-1.0

How do i trigger a 'on-tap' event present in an html string which is inserted to a polymer component like so.

```
<dom-module id="test-comp">

    <template>
        Please <span inner-h-t-m-l="[[htmlString]]"></span> here for an alert!
    </template>

    <script>
        Polymer({

          is: 'test-comp',

          properties: {
              htmlString: {
                  type: String,
                  value: '<a on-tap="doSomething">click</a>'
              }
          },

          doSomething: function () {
              console.log('tap event has happened!');
          }

        });
    </script>

</dom-module>
```

**Actual result:**
Not able to see any tap/click event happening, i guess the on-tap event in the htmlString is not compiled to a polymer event when it is inserted.

**Expected output:**
I should be able to see the output `'tap event has happened!'` when clicked on the 'click' anchor tag in the html rendered sentence

Answer (score 0):

It is not really clear to me what you want to achieve here.
However, I do not believe that your shown approach is in either way clean or recommended.
If you want to add and remove a function depending on some state you could [Imperatively add and remove listeners](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events)

```
this.listen(this.$.myButton, 'tap', 'onTap');
this.unlisten(this.$.myButton, 'tap', 'onTap');
```

In case you are looking to switch functions depending on a state I would do this in a decision function:

```
<dom-module id="test-comp">

  <template>
    <span on-tap="alertSwitch"></span>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({

      is: 'test-comp',

      alertSwitch: function() {
         if(a){
           this.alertOne();
         } else {
           this.alertTwo();
         }
      },
      alertOne: function () {
          console.log('first tap event has happened!');
      },
      alertTwo: function () {
          console.log('second tap event has happened!');
      }

    });
  </script>

</dom-module>
```

It is not really clear what you goal is here.